Finding wifi encryption key in memory
I wanted to know whether the encryption keys derived for data encryption are stored in RAM or not after establishing a Wi-Fi connection in WPA2 and WPA3 protocols. If the answer is yes, can these keys be extracted from RAM? how? If the answer is negative, then the extracted keys are stored and kept in cache for data encryption during the key generation stage?

I would expect that the answers would be extremely implementation dependent

do you have any information which can guide me to the right answer?

I don't have information about any specific WPA2,3 implementation; however if you mention the implementation you are interested in, perhaps someone else will be able to answer
